# How to constrain ListView in Flutter based on viewport height

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, constraints, flutter-layout

I'm trying to limit a ListView based on viewport height so that it scrolls if more items exist in it, but I haven't found a way to successfully do that without providing a fixed number on a SizedBox.

Layout looks like this:

```
- SingleChildScrollView
       - SizedBox (height equal to MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)
               - Column
                   - Text
                     - TextField
                         - SizedBox (because I found no other way)
                              - ListView
```

Something to note here is that I don't want the List to scroll along the the rest of the view but on its own leaving textfield always in view.

[image]

Comment: What problem are you getting now

Comment: why not `Column[Text, TextField, Expanded > ListView]`?

Comment: Without a Scroll container when the keyboard opens I get the overflow error.

Comment: Check the below solution I which I have texfield when keyboard appear there will not appear the error at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the whole screen scroll when data is exceed from the device height then you need to use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget which scrolls when data is exceed from the device height. I have created the example of it in which i have used the `MediaQuery` for the proper size of the widget .Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildPage();
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return SafeArea(
      top: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView (

            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    height: MediaQuery
                        .of(context)
                        .size
                        .height * 0.2,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Ravindra Kushwaha", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0
                      ),),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    child: TextField(

                    ),
                  ),

                  Expanded(
                    child: _buildList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            title: Text('First'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)

        ),
        ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            title: Text('Seond'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)

        ),
        ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            title: Text('Third'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)

        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And Output will be following.

[image]

Comment: It is much better however in order to see the last entry of the list I need to also scroll the whole view, so it is more like double scroll now.

Comment: You can remove the singlescollview to avoid the whole screen screen instead of the listview scroll